# Alternatives for VS

Tags: visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternatives to MS Visual Studio .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628410/alternatives-to-ms-visual-studio-net)

Hy guys. 
I'm looking for an IDE with highlight colors(allternatives for visual studio).
with support to C#/ASP.net Javascript/Jquery

Comment: What's the problem with VS? I mean, for C++, I'd understand, but it's a great IDE for C# and the express version is freely available

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)?